# How to handle secure session in angular 4

Tags: angular, rest, jwt

I am new in angular 4. my question is how to handle security in angular4. I am using rest web service and JWT token for user information.

My login flow is:

> User Login -> Return JWT token -> store in local storage/session
>   storage.

Send this JWT Token to every request.

Now if i copy this token in other browser it will display information of other user.

So I want if user copy paste token to other browser/private window then user logedout.

Any idea???

Comment: Don't waste your time on this. It will allways be possible to copy tokens/sessions/cookies betweek browsers/tabs.

Comment: @ Robin Dijkhof So how i handle session ??

Comment: I don't understand your question right now. What do you want to do with sessions?

Answer (score 0):

A server cannot possible detect if the user copied the JWT to another browser. E.g. you could store the user agent in the JWT and check if the user agent string from the HTTP request and the JWT is the same, but this could be easily circumvented by an attacker.

You could bind the JWT to a specific IP though.

Answer (score 0):

There's always a way to "steal" cookies and tokens from another user, paste them in your browser, and therefore steal user's session. 
Take a look at [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

There's no 100% defense from it.

Sure, you can store some additional information like `MAC` addresses or smth and map them with your `JWT` tokens, but basically, it'll be pointless.